# Reading from RTSP stream via opencv+ffmpeg results in "method SETUP failed: 501 Not Implemented"

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I have a camera setup and running in my local network.
I can see the video stream via VLC without any issues.
Now I am trying to run the following code to also observe the stream with python + opencv.

I am using:

- Python 3.11
- opencv-python 4.8.1.78

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(
    "rtsp://192.168.234.127:8554/h264", 
)

while cap.isOpened():
    status, frame = cap.read()
    
    cv2.namedWindow("frame", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This results in the script being stuck at `cap.read()` with the following error occuring in the background: `[rtsp @ 0000020008b7cd40] method SETUP failed: 501 Not Implemented`. Note that `cap.isOpened()` returns `True`.

I tried:

- downgrading to Python 3.11 from 3.12
- running this in jupyter notebook
- running this directly from script
- force reinstalling opencv-python
- using "rtsp://192.168.234.127:8554/jpeg" instead of "rtsp://192.168.234.127:8554/h264"

  - note that both methods work in the VLC player

edit:

- simplified code, same result.

Comment: that error comes from ffmpeg. use ffmpeg/ffplay from the command line to read the stream. that will probably also fail. that means it's an ffmpeg issue, not an opencv issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Http error 501 - The request method is not supported by the server and cannot be processed. Try check your server, camera. Try use http with mp4 or like it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is actually my work-around for now. In my opinion there must be some bug (or missing capabilities) to interact with the camera, the way my script does. Same scripted worked well when I used another camera.